# rename multiple labels in a panel VB

Tags: object, renaming

I am new to VB and have a question about renaming labels

I have 64 labels I have added to a panel and would like to know if its possible to rename them all at once using code, for example Square1, Square2 etc.

Thanks for taking time to look

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

If they are inside a Panel called Panel1

```
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each lb As Label In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)
        lb.Text = "A" & i
        i += 1
    Next
```

If you want to change the labels inside the Form... `Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)`